# How to move "initial" node in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Okay so when starting a diagram in TikZ I have defined all the other nodes relative to the first node.

```
\node (1)                  {$1$};

\node (2)  [below of=1]    {$2$};

\node (3) [right of=2]    {$3$};

\node (4) [right of=3]    {$4$};
```

and so on. I have finished my diagram but want to move everything more up and to the left as the diagram is closer to the right border than the left. Since everything is determined based on the position of the first node is it possible to just shift that 1st node and have everything else simply just move with it. I tried:

```
\node (1)   [xshift=-3cm,yshift=-3]               {$1$};

\node (2)  [below of=1]    {$2$};

\node (3) [right of=2]    {$3$};

\node (4) [right of=3]    {$4$};
```

yet xshift and yshift don't work for the first node only the others. Is this possible?

Comment: `\node at (4,1) ....`

Comment: Sorry I am very poor at latex where do I write that?

Comment: I tried writing \node at various values but it didn't move the node at all???

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!As percusse says, rather than writing `\node (1);` use `\node (1) at (4,1);` to place the node at position `x=4` and `y=1`.  Also rather than positing code snippets, in future can you please give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). This should start with a `\documentclass` command, load all relevant packages, compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Okay I will do that thanks. I tried the \node(1) at (4,1) but it didn't move at all :(

Comment: If there are no other things in the picture, it wouldn't matter where you put the initial node. TikZ will clip to the smallest possible box. If you need to position relative to origin. Put `\node at (0,0) {};` in your picture then move things around.

Comment: What do you mean by *border* here? @percusse has explained why your attempt didn't work, but if you want to modify the position of the entire `tikzpicture` on the page, then some more context of how the `tikzpicture` environment is placed in the code would be nice.

Comment: For centering picture in the text area use something like `\begin{figure}\centering ... <your TikZ picture> ... \caption{...}\end{figure}` or `\begin{center} ... <your TikZ picture> ... \end{center}`.

Answer (score 3):

When you write up your TikZ code, it internally keeps track of something called the bounding box. It is basically a rectangle and it keeps track of the corners of it by checking what has been entered.

Now imagine you placed something at (0,0) and (5,3). Then TikZ will keep track of these and when it encounters `\end{tikzpicture}` it dispatches to TeX as *"I'm a box of 5 wide and 3 high"*. You put something else outside these coordinates then it will enlarge it.

Notice that it will dispatch the same thing if had placed stuff at (2,2) and (7,5) because the box will be same size. Therefore TikZ clips everything outside the bounding box. That's why no matter where you put things if they are the same relative to each other you will get the same result.

If you want to place things absolutely to somewhere then you have to modify the bounding box either by putting a dummy invisible thing somewhere

```
\node at (0,0) {};
```

or create a custom bounding box at the end of your picture

```
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (10,5);
```

Then TikZ will use that as the bounding box instead of its own tracking.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I had a similar problem and I wanted to share my solution.
I simply added `\hspace{-2em}` before my "initial" node and worked.